# Using import relative path in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import `Dashboard` from `LoginPage` component.

[image]

I tried

`import Dashboard from './scenes/Dashboard`
`import Dashboard from './Dashboard`
`import Dashboard from '../../Dashboard`

but they all didn't work.

What is the correct way to import it?

Answer (score 0):

If the component name is 'DashboardComponent' exported using export default, you can import by,

`import DashboardComponent from '../Dashboard/DashboardComponent'`

if it is not `default` export, it can be imported using {} as,

`import {DashboardComponent} from '../Dashboard/DashboardComponent'`